# Sorting columns in such a way that each column contains only the same values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, memory-management

I am going to give a very simplified example of what I want (because I am working with a very large dataset so hopefully this task is actually doable)

Let's say I have the following dataframe with the following rows,  columns and corresponding values:

```
A     B     C
1     2     5     
2     3     7
3     7     9
```

to become

```
A    B   C   D   E   F
1    2       5
     2   3       7
         3       7   9
```

so essentially, to summarize, I want every column to only have one number (but I also want the code to be applicable to strings rather then just integers because that's what I am doing to be using) and I want every row to preserve all the numbers that it originally had, just that they will be distributed to many columns. Also, I currently have roughly 400,000 rows and 300 columns to work with and will of course need to create much more columns in order to do this so the issue of computational expensive is here as well. Any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT:

I am adding a very small sample from the actual dataset as it probably better informs the type of data I am working with:

```
  1               2             3
0 220008-926      22008-970     None
1 10755-JT        None          None
2 16218-230       None          None
3 None            16218-230     10755-JT
```

I want the above converted to the following

```
     22008-926       22008-970     10755-JT    16218-230

0    22008-926       22008-970
1                                  10755-JT
2                                              16218-230 
3                                  10755-JT    16218-230
```

afterwards to show up as the following, but this last step I can do once I have the previous one figured out (currently the headers are just 1, 2, 3... instead of 22008-926, 22008-970, 10755-JT)...

```
  22008-926       22008-970     10755-JT        16218-230 
0     1              1             0               0
1     0              0             1               0
2     0              0             0               1
3     0              0             1               1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
def expand_arr(a):  # a is array  
    unq = np.unique(a)
    m,n = a.shape[0], len(unq)
    out = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=a.dtype)
    out[np.arange(m)[:,None], np.searchsorted(unq, a)] = a
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [280]: df
Out[280]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  5
1  2  3  7
2  3  7  9

In [281]: pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values))
Out[281]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

Comment: I really like the concept `np.searchsorted(oneDarray, nDarray)`

Comment: @piRSquared It was some magical moment for me, fit right into my hands getting those col indices in that straight-forward way.

Comment: I came up with several ways to do this, but that searchsorted is tough to beat.  I'll be thinking of ways to use this in other contexts.

Comment: Hi, for this I am getting the following error, I think its because my data types area all objects (sorry I might have not been to clear about this in the original question). They can't be converted to integers because they are actually things like 123-456-GB etc, this is the error I get when running your code, was wondering if you have any suggestions: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I got the exact same error message on Option 2 MultiLabelBinarizer for what piRSquared posted below

Comment: @mkheifetz I would suggest posting a minimal representative sample (with object dtype data) in your question alongwith the expected output.

Comment: @Divakar, yep I just updated with a sample example that hopefully shows the type of data I am dealing with better.

Comment: @mkheifetz I am not seeing any error when I run my codes on your edited sample case. It has just one extra column of Nones.

Comment: @Divakar, I have not done it on this mini sample that I created here for illustration purposes but I certaintly can't get it to work on the whole thing... Do you have any thoughts on why I might be getting that error?

Comment: @mkheifetz If you can reproduce the error with some minimal sample data, I might dig into it. Other than that, I am not getting much of clue.

Comment: is there a way to screenprint a dataframe into here? I am not sure how to paste it into here...

Comment: @mkheifetz I guess you can upload on some public storage site like imgur and link it in here to us.

Comment: I just created a very small numpy array, converted it to a dataframe and got this code to work... why it does not work on my huge dataset, beats me, though I am definitely thinking its got to do with me having strings/objects vs integers? Also, I updated my question to ask about how to change the headers to the numbers in the column (as well as change everything else to 0's and 1's, though I think the later should be simple for me to do). How can these operations in your code be made to apply to strings?

Comment: Hi Divakar, thank you for your response, it accomplished exactly what I wanted! However, I didn't think clear enough that I needed one extra functionality. Right now, after I ran your code, all my columns are just named 1, 2, 3, etc.... How can I modify the code in order for each of the column header names to be equal to the value in that column? Would you by any chance be able to add comments for all your lines of code (I am still fairly weak in python, it can be challenging for me to follow). Thank you very much!

Comment: @mkheifetz Try : `pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values), columns=df.columns)`.

Comment: ok I gave that a shot and I get: 
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (24923, 5000), indices imply (99, 5000)                                                                                                       not sure why it is giving me because the previous code that you wrote in your original response worked perfectly fine, it creates the 24923 columns so I am not sure why it is giving me this error message because what you just showed seems very logical to me (the 99 is the size of the dataframe before the transformation that resulted before executing your original code)

Comment: @mkheifetz Sorry, disregard that comment code : `pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values), columns=df.columns)`. It won't work because the output dataframe might have different no. of cols that the input. Now back to your comment, you asked - `How can I modify the code in order for each of the column header names to be equal to the value in that column? `. Now this is not clear to me, because I am not sure how to interpret : `.. value in that column`. A column would have many values. So, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sure, thank you for your very prompt responses by the way, I really appreciate it, I wish I would give you more then 1 upvote somehow. I mean that because in my columns I currently have only 2 values, a 0 or some other thing, like TG-357, so if the only thing I have in column 1 is TG-357 and 0 I want the column to be called TG-357, if column 2 has only values 12457 and 0, I want the column header for that column to be 12457 etc, etc... does that make sense?

Comment: @mkheifetz Try : `df_out = pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values)); idx = (df_out!=0).values.argmax(0); df_out.columns = df_out.values[idx, np.arange(df_out.shape[1])]` I guess.

Comment: hmmm tried it out, that gave me the identical output to what your original answer gave me where all the column names are just the integer sequence 1, 2, 3, 4....

Comment: @mkheifetz If you have a minimal reproducible sample that reproduces this issue, I could try it out. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: ok I updated my question with that, hopefully it is now easier to understand what I mean? Basically just replace the column titles which are showing up as 1, 2, 3 etc with their non-zero values from the actual columns (but the sample I just updated with shows that well)

Comment: @mkheifetz Seems to be working for your edited sample. Here's what I get : https://pastebin.com/CPhN5gTE

Comment: I don't get it, why do I not get that kind of output then. Btw, is the fact that expand_arr(df.values) has df and df_out.column has df_out, aka they are not the same just a typo on your part? I assumed it was a typo and made my dataframe consistent throughout the line of code but am I missing something here?

Comment: @mkheifetz Assume no typo from side. As I have mentioned before, use your `df` and then do : `df_out = pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values)); idx = (df_out!=0).values.argmax(0); df_out.columns = df_out.values[idx, np.arange(df_out.shape[1])]`.

Comment: ok then I am kind of confused, what is df_out? I thought you just made up a random name to call your dataframe, is that not the case? Like I was just replacing the df in your code with my dataframe name, so what am I replacing df_out with?

Comment: oh Wow!!! I just tried it, it worked! Thank you so much! Can you please explain what the df_out is and the whole line of code is doing? I am going to go try to upvote a few of your other answers so it can give you more points, you have really gone above and beyond in helping me here!!

Comment: @mkheifetz `df_out` is just a name for the output dataframe, nothing fancy there. 1) `df_out = pd.DataFrame(expand_arr(df.values))` gets the output dataframe, without the columns being set as per our requirements. 2) `idx = (df_out!=0).values.argmax(0)` gets us the row indices for the non-zero indices per column. 3)  With `df_out.values[idx, np.arange(df_out.shape[1])`, we get the corresponding non-zero entry per column using [`NumPy's integer indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). ..

Comment: @mkheifetz ... So, with `df_out.columns = df_out.values[idx, np.arange(df_out.shape[1])]`, we are simply assigning the column names with those non-zero entries.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 0**
Clever use of `unstack`

```
v = df.values
r = v.ravel()
pd.Series(r, [df.index.repeat(v.shape[1]), r]).unstack(fill_value=0)

   1  2  3  5  7  9
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

**Option 1**
`pd.get_dummies`

```
d1 = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).astype(int)
d1 * d1.columns.values

   1  2  3  5  7  9
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

We can give letter column names with

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

d1 = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).astype(int)
d1 = d1 * d1.columns.values
d1.columns = list(ascii_uppercase[:len(d1.columns)])
d1

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

---

**Option 2**
`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

mlb.fit_transform(df.values) * mlb.classes_

array([[1, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 3, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 7, 9]])
```

We can wrap that up in a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(
    mlb.fit_transform(df.values) * mlb.classes_,
    df.index, list(ascii_uppercase[:mlb.classes_.size])
)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

---

**Option 3**
`pd.factorize` + `np.bincount`

```
u = np.unique(df)

v = df.values
f, u = pd.factorize(v.ravel())

n, k = v.shape
m = u.size
i = np.arange(n).repeat(k) * m

one_hot = np.bincount(i + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)
one_hot * u

array([[1, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 3, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 9]])
```

We can wrap this in a dataframe as in the other options

```
pd.DataFrame(
    one_hot * u,
    df.index, list(ascii_uppercase[:mlb.classes_.size])
)

   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  0  5  0  0
1  0  2  3  0  7  0
2  0  0  3  0  7  9
```

---

**Timing**
*code below*

[image]

```
def pir_0(df):
    v = df.values
    r = v.ravel()
    return pd.Series(r, [df.index.repeat(v.shape[1]), r]).unstack(fill_value=0)

def pir_1(df):
    d1 = pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).astype(int)
    return d1 * d1.columns.values

def pir_2(df):
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
    mlb.fit_transform(df.values) * mlb.classes_

    return pd.DataFrame(
        mlb.fit_transform(df.values) * mlb.classes_,
        df.index, mlb.classes_
    )

def pir_3(df):
    u = np.unique(df)

    v = df.values
    f, u = pd.factorize(v.ravel())

    n, k = v.shape
    m = u.size
    i = np.arange(n).repeat(k) * m

    one_hot = np.bincount(i + f, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)

    return pd.DataFrame(
        one_hot * u,
        df.index, u
    )

def div_1(df):  # a is array 
    a = df.values
    unq = np.unique(a)
    m,n = a.shape[0], len(unq)
    out = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=a.dtype)
    out[np.arange(m)[:,None], np.searchsorted(unq, a)] = a
    return pd.DataFrame(
        out,
        df.index, unq
    )


results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000],
    columns='pir_0 pir_1 pir_2 pir_3 div_1'.split())

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))

results.plot(logx=True, logy=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. I get a MemoryError when I run the first part of your option 1 code. I am not surprised because I currently have the dataframe at over 400K rows and 300 columns... How should that be addressed? I am guessing this will be a big problem for many different types of operations that I will try to run on it.

Comment: I've verified that all options provide good results.  Do they all result in memory errors?

Comment: And if you have too many unique values... your array will be huge.  You may want to merge the values into bins.  I expect these will be features?

Comment: I have tried the option the other person gave which gave me a different type of Error message, and option 1 that you provided. I am now trying the other ones (it takes a very long time to run most of those) so I will update when I run through them. Yes, I think that what you are saying is precisely the case (regarding the huge). I am trying to work on a market basket analysis where I want to use some items in the basket to recommend other items they should buy type of thing. So I am not sure that binning makes sense in this context since the items are discrete and not continuous

Comment: Check the size of unique values `np.unique(df).size`  If that is on the order of `100` then your resulting array is `400K x 100` or whatever.  None of these solutions will solve that problem.  That's why I suggested binning your values to reduce the number of unique values.

Comment: Yea, it will be way over 100 because my dataset already has 300 columns before the code you suggest which will obviously create way more new columns they will all contain only unique values... So per my comment above, I don't think binning makes sense in this particular context. Is there anything else that can be done? Should Python not be able to handle such large datasets?

Comment: It's not python... It's your computer.  You should ask another question about how to process this large amount of data.  I suspect you'll have to break it into chunks and write to file or database.

Comment: how should I best word that so people understand my question?

Comment: Choose a method here.  Show an example on a small dataframe.  Explain that you cannot do this with a large dataframe and that you'd like to devise a plan to chunk the large dataframe and write this to file or db.  Point out that the issue that if you chunk, you'll have to account for unique values that may show up in another chunk.  This means that every chunk needs to have the same number of final columns.  Share a link back to this question to give more context.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, off topic, I really respect that Top 500 Putnam Finish!

Comment: @mkheifetz thx for that.  My prof convinced me to take it that year.  I wish I had done it other years.  I was very ill prepared.  But it was very fun!  Not many folks know what that is.  You made me smile today.

Comment: I wish I was a math major back in college... There is no way I can solve any of those problems but I sure know all about it... It takes a lot to solve anything on that exam:)

Comment: This is just a thought and I don't know enough about it.  But we may be able to solve the memory issue by using sparse arrays/dataframes... not sure how yet.  But I wanted to let you know just in case I get pulled away before I figure it out.

Comment: is your approach to figuring things out in python similar to solving math problems? I always try to connect the two but always feel like coding requires a lot more knowledge/syntax specific to the language itself that you have to figure out before being able to logically try to come up with how to do something?

Comment: Hey, so what I decided to try to do was do a random sampling of my dataset to make it much smaller using: Top_Randomized = Top_300.take(np.random.permutation(len(Top_300))[:5000])

After that I tried running all 4 of your options, Option 1 still gives me MemoryError but option 0 gives me: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape and Option 2 gives me: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'... what is the reason for this? Is this still related to Memory Issues?